# Connect by lead incremental values Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

```
COL1 COL2
---------
A   1
B   5
C   12
D   14
```

And I would like to obtain this other one. This is, until the next col2 for each col1 is reached, a row with the COL1 and incremental values.

```
COL1 COL2
---------
A   1
A   2
A   3
A   4
B   5
B   6
B   7
B   8
B   9
B   10
B   11
C   12
C   13
D   14
```

EDIT: this is what I've tried so far. It seems I'm not far away from the solution but struggling to progress further than this.

```
WITH aux (
    col1,
    col2
) AS (
    SELECT
        'A',
        1
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'B',
        5
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'C',
        12
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'D',
        14
    FROM
        dual
), aux1 AS (
    SELECT
        a.*,
        nvl(LEAD(a.col2) OVER(
            ORDER BY
                a.col2
        ), a.col2) h
    FROM
        aux a
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aux1
CONNECT BY level >= col2
           AND level <= h;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

testseq is the table containing your initial 4 rows. Use lead to find the stop value for col2 for each col1, and recursion to iterate and create the additional rows.

```
WITH xrows (col1, col2, lastcol2) AS (
        SELECT t.*, LEAD(col2) OVER (ORDER BY col1) - 1
          FROM testseq t
         UNION ALL
        SELECT col1, col2+1, lastcol2
          FROM xrows t
         WHERE col2 < lastcol2
     )
SELECT col1, col2
  FROM xrows
 ORDER BY col1, col2
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find the "next" number (whatever ordering you prefer) and then generate such number of rows with recursive subquery:

```
with a(code, num) as(
  select 'A', 1 from dual union all
  select 'B', 5 from dual union all
  select 'C', 12 from dual union all
  select 'D', 14 from dual
)
, b as (
  select
    a.*
    , lead(num - 1, 1, num) over(order by code asc) as next_num
  from a
)
select
  b.code
  , gen.val
from b
  cross join lateral(
    select num + level - 1 as val
    from dual
    connect by num + level - 1 <= next_num
  ) gen
order by 2 asc
```

Or if you prefer recursive CTE:

```
with a(code, num) as(  
  select 'A', 1 from dual union all  
  select 'B', 5 from dual union all  
  select 'C', 12 from dual union all  
  select 'D', 14 from dual  
)  
, b(code, next_num, val) as (  
  select  
    a.code  
    , lead(num - 1, 1, num) over(order by code asc) as next_num 
    , num 
  from a 
   
  union all 
   
  select 
    code 
    , next_num 
    , val + 1 
  from b 
  where val < next_num 
)  
select  
  b.code  
  , val 
from b 
order by 2 asc
```

| CODE | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 9 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 11 |
| C | 12 |
| C | 13 |
| D | 14 |

[livesql demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/l4wy0lp6aw85aqznsnrz4bdrk)